# How to upload PHAssets in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

In Objective-C I want to upload all PHAssets (images and videos) to my server in background. Can any please suggest me how can I do this?

Comment: background means your app is in background or you dont want see progress and do it in background when app is active.

Comment: post some code that you've tried so far

Comment: The app may in both background and foreground. And the process will be in background method

Comment: you can search for background fetch for minimum interval and its completion handler method

Comment: You can use Background Transfer services of iOS.
http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/

Comment: The problem with background services is that you get limited amount of time for this. If your data is pretty high and internet connection is slow, you might not be able to upload all the PHAssets

Comment: Is it actual for you? I have solution, but need some time for prepare and check code

Comment: ya. It's for my own. Can you please provide me some suggestion.

Comment: Do you have any progress with uploading?

Answer (score 1):

```
let mPhasset : PHAsset = PHAsset()
if mPhasset.mediaType == .image {
    let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
    options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
        return true
    }
    mPhasset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: {(contentEditingInput: PHContentEditingInput?, info: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void in
        if let url = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL {
            // IMPORTANT
            // this url avaiable only in this block
            // we can't perform async operation in bg
            // cause access will expired

            // Now you can copy using FileManager
            // and after this upload copied file
        }
    })

    // Alternative

    let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
    let opt = PHImageRequestOptions()
    opt.resizeMode = .exact
    opt.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    imageManager.requestImage(for: mPhasset,
                              targetSize: CGSize(width: mPhasset.pixelWidth, height: mPhasset.pixelHeight),
                              contentMode: .aspectFill,
                              options: opt,
                              resultHandler:
        { (image: UIImage?, _) in
        // now you can go to background and do whatever you want
        // benefit that you don't need to copy file in main thread
        // which can lag your app
        // disadvantage of this method: we load image in memory
    })

} else if mPhasset.mediaType == .video {
    let options: PHVideoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.version = .current

    PHImageManager.default().requestExportSession(forVideo: mPhasset, options: options, exportPreset: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality, resultHandler: { (session, info) in
        // if we just request video url asset and try upload to server
        // we will have problems with slow mo videos
        // also we will be on the main thread and access for video will expire, if we go to background
        // + size of video is very huge

        guard let session = session else { return }
        session.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "our output path")
        session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        session.exportAsynchronously {
            if (session.status == .completed) {
                // success
            } else {
            }
        }
    })
}
```